How to allow other parent to manage payment details with family sharing?
My wife and I do not have completely merged finances, we both have jobs and our own credit cards.
We do use some family sharing features (e.g. not paying for some apps more than once), so we set that up, but now only I can administer the family sharing because I am the organizer, even though my wife is a parent/guardian.
I want both of us to have permission to administer the account and use our own payment methods if we choose. Options?

There is one account that governs payment. You could swap off each month or quarter or year or have someone let the other manage it.
Would making a third account you use joint payment and joint control over the secrets work as a compromise?
You both could then use your parent count and either could manage the payment card and recording / reconciling purchases. It is awkward on some aspects, though.
You'll have to agree on one form of payment or have the other person load up gift cards on to their account if you really want two sources of funds to combine.

It's not that we don't trust each other with secrets, it's more about it being annoying to go through one person. Third account seems worse. Disappointing. Thanks!

The only thing that goes through one person is setting up the card. I'll try to add an option on carrying gift card balance so the one of you without the primary payment can use their card to add funds to a balance. What else is annoying @durron597 ?
